# Develop ECEF rotational matrix from NED aircraft yaw, pitch, roll

Tags: python, coordinate-system

My goal is given an aircraft's latitude, longitude, altitude, yaw, pitch, and roll all in a NED coordinate system, produce a EFEC X,Y,Z location of the aircraft along with a 3x3 rotational matrix relative to ECEF.

Converting lat, long, alt to X, Y, Z was fairly straight forward using a wgs84 earth model.

The place I am stuck is on the rotational matrix. I can compute one from yaw, pitch, and roll using the following python code:

```
# NOTE: Yaw, Pitch, and Roll are in RADIANS
# Develop  aircraft yaw rotational matrix 
        r_yaw = np.array([[np.cos(yaw), -np.sin(yaw), 0],
                            [np.sin(yaw), np.cos(yaw), 0],
                            [0,0,1]])

        # Develop aircraft pitch rotational matrix
        r_pitch = np.array([[np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)],
                            [0,1,0],
                            [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]])

        # Develop aircraft roll rotational matrix
        r_roll = np.array([[1,0,0],
                            [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)],
                            [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]])

        # Matmul each matrix together in the order of yaw * pitch * roll. 
        a_rotational_mx = np.matmul(np.matmul(r_yaw, r_pitch), r_roll)
```

But for here, if I am understanding this correctly, this rotational matrix would be in the coordinate system of NED, not ECEF. So I can't directly use it until I make another transformation from NED to ECEF. Thing is, I have not found any way to do that.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while on the subject I came across this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aeroblks/directioncosinematrixeceftoned.html

By using latitude and longitude you can rotate your reference frame to that of ECEF from NED. This one actually goes from ECEF to NED but if you want to go the other way just take the transpose of this matrix. After you do that, just apply any transformations you want using the above code.

Hope this helps someone else!

Also found this: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA484864.pdf (page 19 top of the page steps 1-4) and tried to implement it but couldn't seem to get it to work but I'll keep trying!

Comment: did you check navpy ned2ecef function ? https://navpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_docs/coordinate_transformations.html